# put text inside div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to label my picture inside a div container with a name in the h2 tag and health points on the bottom with a p tag, but its not working when I use .text. I am trying to insert the text in the js file, "Darth Vader" into the div h2 in the div container: charContainer

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Week 4 Game</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- Added link to the jQuery Library -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" integrity="sha256- laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .characters
    {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    .vade, .skywalker, .obi, .dmaul
    {
        width: 130px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 35px;
    }
    .charContainer, .charContainer1, .charContainer2, .charContainer3
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 170px;
        float: left;
        border: solid;
        border-color: green; 
        background-color: white;
    }

    h2
    {
        font-size: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    .your
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .enemies
    {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .c1
    {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "characters">
    <div class="charContainer">
        <h2 id="c1"></h2>
        <img class="vade" src="assets/images/vader.jpg">
        <p class="c1hp"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="your">
    <h2>Your Character</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="enemies">
         <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png">
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

JS File

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#c1').text("Darth Vader");


     }
```

Comment: Are missing to close `)` in JQuery ready

Comment: plus, where is the script tag for your JS file?

Comment: missing `);` towards the end

Comment: what do you mean? In the js file?

Comment: I added the ) and its still not working

Comment: Where does the jquery link script go? I put it in the html head

Comment: Where does the `script src` to the JS file located?

Comment: I put it in the<head> in html file

Comment: No, you put a link to the jQuery library in the `head` tag.  It doesn't look like you have a link to your script in there at all.

Answer (score 6):

It's just a typo in your JS file.

Replace:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#c1').text("Darth Vader");
}
```

with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#c1').text("Darth Vader");
});
```

---

**Update 16 Oct 01:46**

1. Your script import of the jQuery library contains an extra space between `sha256-` and `laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4=`
2. You don't reference your JS file anywhere in index.html.

Add:

`<script src="NAME-OF-JS-FILE.js"></script>`

just before your closing `</body>` tag.